# Div Background Image Print Blank

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html page.

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body style="margin: 10px">
       <div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; 
          background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rfbMN3-IFiA/maxresdefault.jpg");
          background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:contain; background-position:center'>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that when I print the page it shows blank. Does that mean that div backgrounds cannot be printed. If so, how can I reform my html page to behave the same way and still be printable? My final goal is to print the image in a way that fits the page.

P.S. I tried to put my code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q04hupuj/) but it doesn't show.

P.S. My ink cartridge is full :)

Comment: Usually, background is not printed by default. You need to goto settings and select print background. [Take a look at this](http://prntscr.com/ammky2)

Comment: does that work in every browser?

Comment: I found it on Chrome but what about IE and FF?

Comment: If it doesnt show, then i guess you need to change settings in printer that you are using by going to advanced settings or something. I'm not completely sure where that setting is, but you can google.

Comment: One way to overcome this is put the image in an `<img>` tag and display it inline in the `div`, that should print the image i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it this way:

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title></title>
   </head>
   <body style="margin: 5px; text-align: center">
        <img style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%"
        src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rfbMN3-IFiA/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" />
   </body>
</html>
```

And [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9f3gynuh/).

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You need to have another CSS stylesheet, with a the media option set to print:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

This would essentially be a copy of your other style sheet but in the above code, its called print.css

the default media is screen, so we usually do not need to set it.

That should do it, but its not going to work in a fiddle, I'll update if I can get a working to show you. Let me know if it works!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/q04hupuj/3)

The following css will work in all browsers:

```
html { 
  background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rfbMN3-IFiA/maxresdefault.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It still prints blank!

Comment: I'm trying. It doesn't seem to work without changing the setting in the browser to print background images.

Comment: you made another style sheet? and added the tag in the head?

Comment: Yes and the tag broke the page.

Comment: the tag broke the page? did you add all the stuff from the fiddle? I just tried it and it works in safari and FF but not chrome, I did a little research, and you will not be able to do this chrome, the only way is the answer above or to more the background image to the foreground....good luck!